# Extract pwdLastSet property for all OU users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to create a list of all OU users and their last password change time/date. Here is a simple code that I use:

```
$OUpath = 'OU=testOU,DC=extranet,DC=domain,DC=com'
$ExportPath = 'D:\TEMP\PassExpired.csv'
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OUpath | Select-object -Property Name,UserPrincipalName,pwdLastSet | Export-Csv -NoType $ExportPath
```

I'm not sure why the first two properties are exported properly and the **pwdLastSet** throws an empty column.

I'm also using this code below to convert the LargeInteger into a standard date/time format and it works as expected:

```
$PassSet = (Get-ADUser -identity user.name -properties pwdLastSet).pwdLastSet
(Get-Date 1/1/1601).AddDays($PassSet/864000000000)
```

Maybe I'm missing something?

Artur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get-ADUser` does not return all the properties. You need to specify them by name, or wildcard (`get-aduser -filter * -SearchBase $OUpath -Properties *`) for all in parameter `-Properties`. 
Also consider using `PasswordLastSet` instead of pwdLastSet, as it returns date time and there is no need of conversion.

```
get-aduser -filter * -SearchBase $OUpath -Properties PasswordLastSet | Select-object -Property Name,UserPrincipalName,PasswordLastSet | Export-Csv -NoType $ExportPath
```

P.S. If you still need to use pwdLastSet, same pricipe would apply

```
get-aduser -filter * -SearchBase $OUpath -Properties pwdLastSet| Select-object -Property Name,UserPrincipalName,pwdLastSet| Export-Csv -NoType $ExportPath
```

Comment: Please don't advice to use `-Properties *`. Stick with the properties you actually need to get.

Comment: Properties * is useful, when you need to see, which properties would be useful to you. I usually run it with get-aduser -identity <NAME> for a single user. But yeah, you are right, using -filter * with -properties * for big AD is not a good practice.

Comment: @IvanMirchev it works like a charm! Thank you :)
BTW
The OU that I use has only 14 thousand users, so it's not very big. The script finishes after 5 seconds.